# How to replace some digits with letters in each line of a file (according to the letter that exist in column 5th and 6th of that line)?

Tags: linux, awk, gsub

I have a file which is space delimited which looks like this:

```
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_210 562_211 562_212 562_213 562_214 562_215 562_216 562_217 562_218 562_219 562_220 562_221 562_222 562_223 562_224 562_225 562_226 562_227 562_228 562_229 562_230 562_231 562_232 562_233 562_234 562_235 562_236 562_237 562_238 562_239 562_240 562_241 562_242 562_243 562_244 562_245 562_246 562_247 562_248 562_249 562_250 562_251 562_252 562_253 562_254 562_255 562_256 562_257 562_258 562_259 562_260 562_261 562_262 562_263 562_264 562_265 562_266 562_267 562_268 562_269 562_270 562_271 562_272 562_273 562_274 562_275 562_276 562_277 562_278 562_279 562_280 562_281 562_283 562_284 562_285 562_289 562_291 562_292 562_294 562_295 562_296 562_400 562_401 562_402 562_403 562_404 562_405 
AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T A 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 2 -1 1 2 0 0 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 2 1 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 0
```

**I want to replace the digits by letters according to column 5th & 6th**

1. Replace `0` by `$5 $5` (two repeat of column 5th) e.g if the 5th column is `T` replace `0` by `T T`
2. Replace `2` by `$6 $6` (two repeat of column 6th) e.g if the 6th column is `C` replace `2` by `C C`
3. Replace `1` by `$5 $6` e.g if the 5th and 6th columns are `T` and `C`, respectively, replace `1` by `T C`
4. Replace `-1` by `? ?`

I have to note that column 5th and 6th can be T, A, C, and G

So what I would like to have as output is:

```
AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T C T T T T T T T C T C T C T C T C T C T T T C T T T T T T T T C C C C T T T T T T T T T T T C T T T T T T T T T T 
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A T T T T T T T T T T T A T A T T T A T A T T T T T T T T T T T T T A A A A A A A T T T A T A T A A A ? ? T A A A T T T T A A T A T A T T T A T T T A A A T A T T T T T A A A A A T A A A A A T T T A A A A A A A A A A A A A T T T A T T T T T T T A A A A A A A A A T T
```

I don't know if this is possible by awk or not! if not I will give a try in python but I would rather a Linux command like awk (which is much faster than python because I'm using a file which has 1.2 million lines and my computer can swap by python!)

Comment: Please post the code you're written so far.  This is not "do my job for me.com".  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried mayn things with 'sed' but it dose not work! I just want to know the commands that are possible to use then I can give it a try by my self!

Comment: What makes you think awk will be faster than python?

Comment: this was my last try but I know it's totally wrong `awk sample.txt 'BEGIN{sum=0;sum1=0} NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^1/) sed $i = $5 $6 ; else if ($i ~ /^2/) sed $i = $6 $6' > out.txt` and so on!

Comment: @mahmood  You are trying to run the script 'sample.txt' on the file named 'BEGIN{sum...'.  You don't want to do that.

Comment: you sample output does not match your specification.  Where do you get a bunch of "A"s from on the 2nd line?

Comment: because in the second line inested of C in column 6th is A so all the 2 will be replaced by A A

Comment: @mahmood and what do you replace `1` with if the 5th and 6th columns are **not** `T C`?  You are missing quite a few permutations. Please update your answer to make the spec complete enough to at least match the sample output you gave. I edited your answer to use a list, please follow that convention

Comment: @mahmood: (1) Please **update** the question to answer the comments.  (2) Please do **not** post code in the comments, please **update** the question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
awk 'NR>1{a=$3;$3="@";gsub(/ -1\>/," ? ?");gsub(/\<0\>/,$5 " " $5);gsub(/\<1\>/,$5 " " $6);gsub(/\<2\>/,$6 " " $6);$3=a;print}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NR>1{
  o="1"; z="0"; t="2"
  if($5 == "T" && $6 == "C")
    o="T C"
  if($5 == "T")
    z="T T"
  if($6 == "C")
    t="C C"
  if($6 == "A")
    t="A A"
  for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) {
    gsub(/1/,o,$i)
    gsub(/0/,z,$i)
    gsub(/2/,t,$i)
    gsub(/-1/,"? ?", $i)
  }
}1
```

#### Output

```
$ awk -f allele.awk allele.in
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_210 562_211 562_212 562_213 562_214 562_215 562_216 562_217 562_218 562_219 562_220 562_221 562_222 562_223 562_224 562_225 562_226 562_227 562_228 562_229 562_230 562_231 562_232 562_233 562_234 562_235 562_236 562_237 562_238 562_239 562_240 562_241 562_242 562_243 562_244 562_245 562_246 562_247 562_248 562_249 562_250 562_251 562_252 562_253 562_254 562_255 562_256 562_257 562_258 562_259 562_260 562_261 562_262 562_263 562_264 562_265 562_266 562_267 562_268 562_269 562_270 562_271 562_272 562_273 562_274 562_275 562_276 562_277 562_278 562_279 562_280 562_281 562_283 562_284 562_285 562_289 562_291 562_292 562_294 562_295 562_296 562_400 562_401 562_402 562_403 562_404 562_405
AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T C T T T T T T T C T C T C T C T C T C T T T C T T T T T T T T C C C C T T T T T T T T T T T C T T T T T T T T T T
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T 1 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A T T T T T T T T T T 1 1 T T 1 1 T T T T T T T T T T T T 1 A A A A A A T T 1 1 1 A A ? ? 1 A A T T T T A A 1 1 T T 1 T T 1 A A 1 T T T T 1 A A A A 1 A A A A T T 1 A A A A A A A A A A A A T T 1 T T T T T T 1 A A A A A A A A T T
```

**Note**: Your spec is still incomplete, you never say what to do with `1` when the 5th and 6th columns are not `T C`, respectively.  There are a number of permutations that you are leaving out.

Comment: that works perfectly I have to do some modification! the only thing is that first you should run `awk 'NR>1{ for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) {gsub(/-1/,"? ?", $i)  }}1' test.txt` since if not the -1 would be transferd to -T or -A and ... something else. and then run the rest of the command. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will also do replacements on the first 4 columns, and I didn't bother with the 1 or -1 case (left as an exercise for the reader), but you should be able to easily expand this to suit:

```
$ perl -lape 's/0/$F[ 4 ] $F[ 4 ]/g; s/2/$F[ 5 ] $F[ 5 ]/g' input
```

I really doubt that awk will be faster than perl at this.

Answer (score 2):

awk is definitely your friend.

awk reads a datafile, line-by-line. You don't need/want to have any kind of loop structure (unless you're getting very advanced).

```
awk '{print $0}' inFile
```

Is all you need to read each line of a file and print it out (it will go to your screen, so don't do a big file)

note that I used `$0` to indicate 'the whole line of data'.

Awk also has variables to refer to each field of data, you use values like `$2` to print the 2nd field in the file.

> I want to replace the digits by letters according to column 5th & 6th. So what I want is to replace 0 with T T (if the 5th column is T) and 2 by C C (if the 6th column is C) and 1 with T C (if the 5th and 6th columns are T and C respectively) and I want to change -1 to ? ? or ! !

So for your problem, you want to test each line, test certain fields and set new values.

```
awk 'NR>1{
  # replace 0 with T T (if the 5th column is T)
  if ($5 == 0) $5="TT"
  # and 2 by C C (if the 6th column is C)
  if ($6 == 2) $6="CC"
  # and 1 with T C (if the 5th and 6th columns are T and C respectively)
  if ($5 == "T" && $6 == "C") $1="1"
}'  inputFile  | sed 's/TT/T T/; s/CC/C C/'
```

To change all fields after a certain field, incorporate this code as needed,

```
awk 'NR>1{
  # replace 0 with T T (if the 5th column is T)
  if ($5 == 0) { 
     for (i=5; i<=NF;i++) {
         printf("T ")
     }
     printf("\n")
 }
 ......
```

}' inputfile ...

The `NR>1` means only processes line numbers greater than 1.

Note that we're using simple logic to implment your tests. it is easy to add more and more. Recall that many times it makes sense to use 'layered' logic `if ($5==0) { ... } else if ($5 == 1) { ....}`

The one problem is your requirement to output 'C C', for example. When you do something like `$5="C C" in awk, awk will recalibrate its field numbers, so $5 will be C and $6 will be C, not the value that was there before.

I have taken the short-cut of printing 'CC', and then using sed at the the end to create the 'C C' values that your specfication indicates.

I'm not sure how to deal with

> and I want to change -1 to ? ? or ! !

as it has to be one or the other, and I'm not sure what field you want to operate on. Use the above code as a guide. If you get stuck, post a new question with sample input data, expected output, current output and the code you are using.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think I asked my question bad or you miss understood me some how! I want to replace from column 7th to the end! and I want to replace them according to what letter exist in column 5 and 6! so I want if it's 0 be replace by $5 $5(I mean two repetition of column 5th) and if it's 1 replace by $5 $6 and if 2 replace by $6 $6 and -1 by ? ?

Comment: you can understand how awk works now from my example? I'll add one more bit. See added sample code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Better to check the field's value by equality instead of by regexp:

```
awk '
    NR==1 {print; next}
    {check0 = check1 = check2 = 0}
    $5 == "T"              {check0 = 1}
    $5 == "T" && $6 == "C" {check1 = 1}
    $6 == "C" || $6 == "A" {check2 = 1}
    {
        for (idx=7; idx <= NF; idx++)
            if      (check0 && $idx == 0) $idx = "T T"
            else if (check1 && $idx == 1) $idx = "T C"
            else if (check2 && $idx == 2) $idx = $6 " " $6
            else if ($idx == -1)          $idx = "? ?"
        print
    }
'
```